# zend framework two step view

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zendframework . I am trying to implement two step view lay out:

Bootstrap.php(view/Bootstrap.php)

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

     public function _initRoutes()
    {
        $options = array(
    'layout'     => 'layout',
    'layoutPath' => '/layout/layout.phtml',);
$layout = Zend_Layout::startMvc($options);
    }
}?>
```

layout.phtml(application/view/scripts/layout/layout.phtml)

```
<?php
        include "header.php";

?>
// view contents goes here.
<?php

       $this->layout()->content;

?>
// footer goes here.
<?php
        include "footer.phtml";
?>
```

i am a absolute beginner step by step explanation is more appreciated .Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to enable layouts is to run the Zend_Tool command from the command line `zf enable layout`, this will add the line
 `resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"`
 to your *application.ini* and build the directory for the layout and the default file `layout.phtml`.

Alternatively you can specify your layout path and default layout name with 2 lines in your *application.ini* file:

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts" //path to layout
resources.layout.layout = master //name of layout without extension
```

other layout/view options may be set in your application.ini to be callled in your view:

```
;View Settings
;*************
resources.view[]=
resources.view.charset = "UTF-8"
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
resources.view.language = "en"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

then in your *bootstrap.php* you can call on these resources to initialize your view:

```
 /**
     * initialize the registry and asign application.ini to config namespace
     */
    protected function _initRegistry() {

        //make application.ini configuration available in registry
        $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
        Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    }

    /**
     * initialize the view and return it
     * @return \Zend_View
     */
protected function _initView() {
        //Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();
        //add custom view helper path
        $view->addHelperPath('/../library/Application/View/Helper');
        //set doctype for default layout
        $view->doctype(Zend_Registry::get('config')->resources->view->doctype);
        //set default title
        $view->headTitle('Our Home');
        //set head meta data
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', Zend_Registry::get(
                        'config')->resources->view->contentType);
        //set css includes
        $view->headLink()->setStylesheet('/css/normalize.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/liquid.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/blueprint/src/typography.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet(
                '/javascript/mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/main.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/nav.css');
        $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/table.css');
        //add javascript files
        $view->headScript()->setFile('/javascript/mediaelement/build/jquery.js');

        //add it to the view renderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                        'ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        //Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }
```

I also included a convenience method _initRegistry() to make config options available everywhere with minimal code.

The layout in ZF is a simple html page with placeholder added for dynamic or configured options:

```
<?php
echo $this->doctype() . "\n"; //placeholder assigned in bootstrap $view->doctype
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta() . "\n" //placeholder assigned in bootstrap ?>
        <?php echo $this->headLink() . "\n" //placeholder assigned in bootstrap ?>
        <?php echo $this->headscript(). "\n" //placeholder assigned in bootstrap?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="container">
            <header class="block">
                <hgroup id="header" class ="column span-24">
                    <h1>Our Page</h1>
                </hgroup>
                <nav>
                    <div id="nav" class="column span-24">
                        <?php echo $this->layout()->nav //custom placeholder ?>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <section class="block">
                <div id="main" class="column span-18 border">
                    <div id="flash">
                        <?php
                        //flash messenger display location
                        if (count($this->messages) > 0) {
                            printf("<h3 id='flash'>%s</h3>", $this->messages[0]);
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; //placeholder for redering views ?>
                </div>
                <aside id="sidebar" class="column span-4 last">
                    <?php echo $this->layout()->search //custom placeholder ?>
                    <div id="subNav">
                        <?php echo $this->layout()->subNav //custom placeholder ?>
                    </div>
                    <div id="adminMenu">
                        <?php echo $this->layout()->adminMenu //custom placeholder ?>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </section>
            <footer class="block">
                <div id="footer" class="column span-24">
                    <p>Created by <em>Your Name</em> with <a href="http://framework.zend.com/">Zend Framework. &COPY; </a></p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
<?php echo $this->inlineScript() ?> //javascript includes at bottom of page
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for time to answer my question. i just implemented the way you explained here. But i am facing some difficulties .echo his->doctype() works perfectly but all other functions like $this->headMeta() ,$this->headLink() not working properly . What will be the reason ? Thanks

Comment: As a beginner it is very hard to learn from zend programmers guide . I need more explanation on each and every bit of code ; if you don't mind can you please refer me to basic tutorial that helps me to resolve this issue .

Comment: $this->layout()->content ,$this->layout()->subNav,echo $this->layout()->adminMenu   Would you please explain this code?

Comment: is this a question.and your name Compiler? wht

Comment: The best I can find as far as tutorials goes is http://devzone.zend.com/1235/view-helpers-in-zend-framework/. Some of these placeholders in my example are custom and the code to implement is not present, in fact at the moment they are just placeholders for code yet to be written.

Comment: But that means that every page of my site has to have each own layout. But this is exactly the repeating of the code! You gave an example of the page with layout. Ok. But this is just one page. And what if my other pages have different design? If layout is just a simple html page then I have to again write the same html-code with little variation for each and every new page. I just cannot understand this concept of Layout from Zend. Why `$this->headMeta()` is called without `layout()` but `$this->layout()->content` is called through `layout()`?

Comment: @Green most pages in a site use a common layout. This is the basis of ZF layout.

Comment: @Green the concept of placeholders allows you to adjust the layout to accommodate differences between pages. Usually involves dynamic content.

Answer (score 2):

Well first off, youre initializing the layout in a method that would seem to be for your routing - probably a bad idea. Secondly if youre using the full stack with [Zend_Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html) then you can use the provided [`Zend_Application_Resource_Layout`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.layout) and set all your [options](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.options.html) from [configuration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.html).

Additionally you dont want to use a raw `include` statement to pull in content you should use `$this->render('thetemplate.phtml')` from within your layout file. Check out the [`Zend_Layout` Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html) for more info on that.